# Autorunning HTML and PHP from a CD. Is it possible?

Tags: php, html

So for an assignment, we have to create a 15 page website. But I was going to use some PHP for a few things. One of the requirements is that I write the files to a CD, set up to Autorun.

One of the problems I've discovered with PHP is that it has to run from a server. Does this mean that I can't use PHP for this assignment?

Edit: Size limit is 100MB

Comment: php is a server side technology. What would the php achieve?

Comment: It's just to help in a few parts of the different pages, if it can't be done with a method that can be justified that I will just do it the long way around. Just convenience and trying to be "smart" I guess. We get some marks for "clever" coding and since PHP isn't a requirement, it comes under being clever.

Comment: @ChrisMellor As a professor, I'm not sure I'd count running PHP off autorun as clever. Is there actually anything you couldn't do with JavaScript and stuff like localStorage?

Comment: You're right, using PHP isn't that clever at all, describing it as an extra unusual in terms of what we've been taught is probably is a better idea. I just wanted to use PHP since I've had a bit of experience with it. 

But I can learn enough JS to get by and carry on learning it once I've finished with the assignment. I intended to learn JS this summer.

Answer (score 1):

While it wouldn't be PHP on the CD itself, you can still use PHP to compile the components (header, footer, etc) and content of each of the pages into their final HTML files (and directories). In essence you'd be making a light static site generator.

Comment: So what do you mean? I can type out the PHP code and it'd still work when it is running from the CD?

Comment: You would make your layout file, and make the files for the content of each page, and use php to combine them into the output html files. It'd be like creating your own static site generator, similar to https://jekyllrb.com/ or https://sculpin.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try [FoxServ Win32 & Linux Edition](https://sourceforge.net/projects/foxserv/)

or

[DWebPro](http://www.dwebpro.com/)

It's exactly what you need!

Comment: I don't need to install anything or help writing to the CD. Just to know if it's possible to run the PHP without a server from the CD

Answer (score 0):

Php with embeded server should be the way to go.. So, You'll need some sort of portable variant of php 5.4+ on a cd and a shell script that calls it ... Anyway, there are still people using CD's nowadays? Weird. :D

Comment: This is basically an "and then magic happens" answer. How would you go about doing that, particularly in a cross-OS manner?

Comment: Well, windows has a powershell that can run bash scripts and this -> `http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php` would be the key part.

Comment: Would all this come under 100MB? I didn't think that I would need to mention that. My bad. But yeah, it's purely for the assignment, I doubt in a real life situation writing it to a CD would actually be done.

Comment: I really can't answer that. PHP it self is under 20mb, but how many images and the rest of files there are for those 15 pages of Yours, that's something what you should know.. 100mb for a 15 page website wihtout db and video files and audio files and without gigantic pdf's is extremely too much if you ask me.